# Pytorch - Batch Normalizaiton simple question

Tags: pytorch, batch-normalization

I implemented a model with batch normalization:

```
class FFNet(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, D_in, H_1, H_2, D_out):

        super(FFNet, self).__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(D_in, H_1)
        self.linear2 = torch.nn.Linear(H_1, H_2)
        self.bn2 = torch.nn.BatchNorm1d(H_2)
        self.linear4 = torch.nn.Linear(H_2, D_out)

    def forward(self, x):

        h_relu_1=F.relu(self.linear1(x))
        h_relu_2=F.relu(self.bn2(self.linear2(h_relu_1)))
        y_pred=self.linear4(h_relu_2)
        return y_pred
```

Also, I wrote the training loop:

```
for epoch in range(epoches):

    running_loss = 0.0
    cnt = 0
    for i, data in enumerate(train_data, 0):
        local_X, local_y = data
        y_pred = model.forward(local_X)
        loss = criterion(y_pred, local_y)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        #loss = criterion(y_pred, Y_local_output)
        loss.backward() # back props
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss = running_loss + loss.item()
        cnt+=1


    Validation_loss = 0.0
    cnt2 = 0
    # Validation
    for i, data in enumerate(validation_data, 0):
        Val_X, Val_Y = data

        y_pred = model.forward(Val_X)

        loss=criterion(y_pred, Val_Y)
        Validation_loss = Validation_loss + loss.item()
        cnt2+=1
```

I have two questions:
1. Is there no need to use model.train() in this code?
2. How to evaluate this model using `eval`? I have one data sample whose size is (1xD_in), and batch size is more than 1. When I use the below code, there is an error:

```
    test_single = torch.tensor([aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ag])
    test_single = test_single.unsqueeze(0)

    model.eval()
    [bb,cc] = model.forward(test_single)
```

The error is 'not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)'

Answer (score 1):

If you have batch normalization, then you do need to use model.train() and model.eval() while training and evaluating respectively.

The 2nd part (the unsqueezing code) is not wrong. However, there is only one output of your model (see the return statement of your model's forward function), which causes the error i.e. you try to unpack 2 values whereas there is only one. So, you can't do

```
[bb,cc] = model.forward(test_single)
```

You have to do

```
out = model.forward(test_single)
```

I tried this and it works.

Comment: Thank you for your kindness.
Did you mean that I have to add the sentence model.train() and model.eval() in the code? I wonder I should add those sentences when training and validation.

Also, model has two outputs. However, that kinds of error exists...

Comment: Yes, you have to add `model.train()` before starting the for loop for training. Same for validation and `model.eval()`. As far as the model you show in the question, the forward function returns only one value. So, when you call the forward function (using `model(input)`), then you can't expect it to return 2 outputs.